# How to work with different threads in different iframes at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, iframe

**TL;DR:**

Two threads interfere each other because of different webdriver status (different switch_to()-states) (see code example '1)' and '2)').

**More detailed:**

There is a website (not mine, access restricted, can't show here) with 1 main page and 3 iframes within.
At the mainpage is a counter - I read the value of that counter every second.
Then I have a GUI, where I can interact with QSlider that emits changes to one of the 3 iframes.

So I have a GUI-Thread and another thread (e.g. that checks time).

Where the problem happens:
If the QSlider-signal emits, the called function changes the webdriver to the specific frame (switch_to()) and when in between the mainpage-countdown-checker wants to read the countdown, it can't find the element, because the webdriver is not at the mainpage.

**Code example**

Here you can see the two functions who interfere each other because called from 2 different threads:

1) This function is called because the GUI emits a signal. To change the specific element at the website, it needs to switch the webdriver to the specific frame:

```py
def click_rating(driver, frame, rating, slider=None, value=None):

    try:
        driver.switch_to.frame(frame)  // SWITCH TO SPECIFIC FRAME
        if slider is None or value is None:
            for i in range(2, 9):
                driver.find_element_by_id("OneChoiceQuestion" + str(i) + str(rating[i-2])).click()
        else:
            driver.find_element_by_id("OneChoiceQuestion" + str(slider+2) + str(value)).click()
    except InvalidArgumentException:
        print("InvalidArgumentException Error: [Deleted].")
    finally:
        driver.switch_to.default_content()  // SWITCH BACK
```

2) This function is called regularly to check the countdown timer but it depends on webdriver being in 'default_content()':

```py
def get_passed_time_counter(driver):
    try:
        if driver.find_element_by_id("alarmClock").is_displayed():
            minutes = int(driver.find_element_by_id("alarmClock").text[11:13])
            seconds = int(driver.find_element_by_id("alarmClock").text[14:16])

            new_time = 180 - ((60 * minutes) + seconds)

            return new_time

    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError [update_time]: Couldn't update the time.")
        return False
```

The countdown timer is not the only problem but probably the best one to explain.
So I'm not searching for a 'hotfix' where I just try to find the countdown element until I've found it but to find a structure for this kind of situation where it waits while another thread uses specific functions and I wouldn't like it to work with boolean-flags as long as there might be a 'clean' solution for that.

Comment: Please ask or tell me if there're informations missing or if it is a topic like "It's not possible because you should never do something like that".